# How to add a prefix and suffix to a particular word occurrences in the String?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to add prefix and suffix to a particular occurrence of the word in the string in java. Can anyone help me and tell me where am i going wrong? Below is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello world. welcome world java.";
        String arr[] = str.split("[. ]");
        if(str.contains("world")) {
            System.out.println("PREFIX_"+str+"_SUFFIX");
        }
    }
```

**output expected** :

```
Hello PREFIX_world_SUFFIX. welcome PREFIX_world_SUFFIX java
```

**output getting**:

```
PREFIX_Hello world. welcome world java_SUFFIX
```

Comment: After calling split(), your slices of sentence is in arr[], at that moment, str contents is not touched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong since you're not changing the `str` variable while calling the split() function.
Also, from what I can gather, you also want to add prefix and suffix to those words containing "world".
Like if your string is something like this: `Hello worldJava! welcome to java world`, you'd want to display something like this: `Hello PREFIX_worldJava_SUFFIX! welcome to java PREFIX_world_SUFFIX`. (Note, the previous answers wouldn't be able to do this kind of substitution).

```
    String str = "Hello world. welcome world java.";
    String[] wordArr = str.split("[. ]");
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(wordArr));
    for (String w: words) {
        if(w.toLowerCase().contains("world")){
            str = str.replace(w, "PREFIX_"+ w +"_SUFFIX");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Note here that I am using java Set to parse unique words from the input string and then replacing them in the original string with the added prefix/suffix.

Answer (score 5):

```
String replaced = str.replaceAll("world", "PREFIX_world_SUFFIX");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this simply :

```
public class Example {

     public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "Hello world. welcome world java.";
        System.out.println(str.replace("world", "PREFIX_world_SUFFIX"));
     }
}
```

Output :

```
Hello PREFIX_world_SUFFIX. welcome PREFIX_world_SUFFIX java.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong on the print side. You can do this.

```
String stringToCheck = "world";

if(str.contains(stringToCheck)) {
 str = str.replaceAll(stringToCheck , "PREFIX_"+stringToCheck+"_SUFFIX");
 System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: what to do if the word is case sensitive? let's say, 'World' and 'world' and i have to enclose both of them.

Comment: this solution is case sensitive. but if u want it to be case insensitive. use the toLower() function in string. str.toLower().contains(stringToCheck.toLower()) 
for better result please explore aphace string utils 

Case insensitively replaces all occurrences of a String within another String.

StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase(str, stringToCheck , "PREFIX_"+stringToCheck+"_SUFFIX")

Comment: @AkshayShinde Try to put that info in post , that very important info

Comment: @JoseMarlonAncajas That will not work since `World` in previous string became `world`. But OP just want to add prefix and suffix

Comment: @JoseMarlonAncajas it's perhaps easier to use a case-insensitive regex to do the replacement, and then check if the string changed length.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks - Yes, it actually long code for java core alone. but if OP is not restricted, can use StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase() and StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase() both in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils. to make things essier.

Comment: @JoseMarlonAncajas You didn't get it. I said `Hello World` became `Hello PREFIX_world_SUFFIX` not  `Hello PREFIX_World_SUFFIX`

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks yes, I saw that better not use toLowerCase(). case-insensitive regex is the solution as mention by Andy Turner

Comment: @JoseMarlonAncajas Accutally No, case-insensitive regex also not solve this because you need to give a fixed replace string that makes same problem

Comment: Please dont use `replaceAll` but `replace` if you do not intend to use regex (both replace all occurrences, the naming is bad).